# Error connecting to SQL Server after Power failure

Tags: mysql, asp.net, visual-studio, iis

EDIT: I'm dumb.  apparently the project was set to use a really old session server.  The entry was buried down in the web.config and none of us realized it was still pointed to that old server for the session database.  And that server didn't power back up after the power failure.

---

I'm getting the following error when I try to run my project:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)
>
> ....
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): Unable to connect to SQL Server session
>   database.]

This project was working fine when I left the office last night, but at some point we had a power failure, and both my desktop and our server on our local network both went down.  I have other projects that connect to the same database server, and those are all still working.  I can open up the database in SSMS and run queries on it with no problem.  I have tried deleting temporary files from a few different places.  I've restarted IIS several times.  I've rebooted my PC, flushed my DNS, cleaned the solution, etc...

I'm stumped...

Someone else in my office just tried and he's getting the same error, so I'm pretty sure that the problem isn't specific to my PC.

Comment: Try switching to ip address instead of servername.

Comment: really thought you were on to something there.  No luck though.

Comment: #1 this is about asp.net session. So if you need to just keep working while the dba figures it out, switch to inproc.

Answer (score 3):

You sure it's online? Try to reboot it
Try to reload the links. At some point there's the chance that on the power failure, one of the two parts got no answer and hasn't checked if the other was online again, so just keeps repeating the last message.

Comment: I am sure that the server is online.  I can run queries against it through SQL-Server Management Studio, and I have another project that uses the same database that is still working.  I'm rebooting the server right now anyways to see if that does anything.

Comment: nope.  rebooted the server and still get the same error

Answer (score 2):

Can you connect to the sql server locally? Is it running? You might need to start it by hand. Is it listening on the port where it should?

Comment: it's MSSQL, not mysql, guess I should have specified that.  And yes, it's running.  I can run queries against it, and I have another project that uses the same DB that works just fine.